# How to access Kafka Connector (confluent log connect) in a docker enviroment

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am currently working with kafka based on confluent's cp-demo project. (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo)

I am developing a custom connector which I was able to publish in the **connect** docker, however it is not working properly and I am having trouble accessing the confluent log to check how it is working.

I know about the existance of `confluent log connect` command which in my localhost enviroment allows me to access the log. How can I access this very same log in this docker environment?

Can anyone show me the path?

Thank  you in advance!

Comment: Try running ```docker exec -it {containerId} confluent log connect ```

Comment: docker exec lets you run commands on running container. you can run above to get logs in interactive mode or you can ssh 'in into container by ```docker exec -it {containerId} /bin/bash```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confluent` cli command doesn't exist in the containers. You would just use [`docker logs <<container-id>>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/), or similar with `docker-compose logs`

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007! With your answer I was able to access the logs! Very nice!

Comment: And how do I tail this log?